# How to Search Outlook Archives (Windows 7 with Indexing Disabled)

Tags: search, microsoft-outlook-2007

On my Windows 7 machine, when I search my mail folders in Outlook 2007, it won't search my archive folders even though I have "Search All Mail Items" checked.  An internet search has only shown results stating that the archive folders need to be indexed in order for Outlook to search them.

But, I disabled indexing by turning off "Windows Search" service and then clicked "Rebuild" under Indexing Options | Advanced Options (which deletes the index but it can't be rebuilt because the service is off).  This has allowed me to do file searches without having to worry about if the file I'm looking for has been indexed or not.

Is there some way to get Outlook to search my archives without indexing?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there some way to get Outlook to search my archives without
>   indexing?

Yes, with a third party utility: *Agent Ransack*

http://www.mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?type=agentransack&page=home

:)

Comment: As of October 2016 Agent Ransack does not appear to support .pst file searching. Instead you must buy File Locator Pro.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the archive folders into your outlook profile so they open as folders when Outlook opens, turn indexing back on, then Windows search will index the archive folder as well (even though they are on your disk and not in your mailbox)

You can see this by looking at Indexing Options in Control Panel and clicking Modify to see what all is being indexed.

BTW - search without index is extremely slow.

Comment: Hi, my archive folders are open when I start Outlook.  My file searches are quite fast and because I have indexing off, it actually finds the files I'm looking for which is more important to me than speed (versus quickly not finding them when indexing was on).  That's why I'm looking for a solution with it off.

Comment: How can you configure Outlook to search without Indexing? I'd rather it start now and be slow than wait 20-30 minutes before it finishes indexes my .pst files.